# .NET Merge Single Column from datarows when ID matchs

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq, dataset

Just in advance, I have no access to the SQL query written, so all I can do is try to handle the dataset after the query has executed. 
I'm using ASP.NET Webforms to try and merge only one column across a SQL returned datatable e.g

```
PID | C1 | C2 | C3 | I1

1   | a  | a  | a  | bob

1   | x  | x  | x  | Jim

1   | b  | b  | b  | Fred

2   | g  | g  | g  | Jill
```

From this Dataset I would like to see:

```
PID | C1 | C2 | C3 | I1

1   | a  | a  | a  | bob Jim Fred

2   | g  | g  | g  | Jill
```

Essentially I don't care what is in C1-C3, it will just take the values of the first match. What I need to do though is join all the values of I1 into the one result based on a matching PID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. LINQ answers acceptable, preferably in vb.net so I don't have to change it later.

Thank you.

Comment: You can try `String.Join` with the `Join` to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group by` with the `String.Join`. Ia,m adding answer in `c#` you might want to convert to `vb`(I not very well with vb syntax :P).

```
  var result = dataListObject.GroupBy(l =>  l.PId )
                 .Select(g => new { PID = g.Key.PId, C1= g.Key.C1, C2 = g.Key.C2, C3=g.Key.C3, I1 = string.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.I1)) });
```

Should select the first PID, C1 ,C2 and C3. Then join the I1 together. Haven't checked this but seems like it should work.

**UPDATE**
For datatable you can apply the `AsEnumerable()` to datatable to make it enumerable

```
   var result = datatable.AsEnumerable().GrouBy(l=>l.Field<string>("Pid"))
               .Select(g=>new{PID = g.Key.PId, C1= g.Key.C1, C2 = g.Key.C2, C3=g.Key.C3, I1 = string.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.I1)) });
```

Comment: Hi, nice clean query. How would I make this work for a datatable. Thank you.